# How to interpret this depiction of an op-amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, memristor

I haven't used/seen this type of op-amp depiction before, so I'm having trouble understanding it. The research paper (linked below) says that this is an [AD844AN](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD844.pdf) chip, but even after looking through the datasheet I'm confused which port is the positive/negative terminal and which is the output and what is the last 4th port. Is it the supply voltage? Then shouldn't there be the negative supply port as well?

Research paper: Lai, F and Zhang, W. “[Design of the floating-type memristor emulator and its circuit implementation.](https://www.ijres.org/papers/Volume%203/v3-i12%20Ver%202/G3124450.pdf)” (2015) *International Journal of Research in Engineering and Science (IJRES), Volume 3 Issue 12 | December 2015 | pp.44-50*

[image: memristor emulator]

By reading through the paper, I can tell that x and y ports are the positive and negative terminals but I cannot tell which is which. Here U1 and U2 are the op-amps and U3 is an analogue multiplier.

[image: extract from the research paper]

Comment: C-137 - Usually, for questions about a published paper, I would consider writing to the "corresponding author" (CA) who typically has their contact details on the paper. Although I work in industry, not academia, I have received replies from CAs to my relevant questions on their paper. However I don't see CA contact details on the paper you are quoting. That's ... odd. Also see [this opinion](https://journalsearches.com/journal.php?title=International%20Journal%20of%20Research%20in%20Engineering%20and%20Science?(IJRES)) about that journal. Those "schematics" are poor (crossing lines etc.) :(

Comment: That article tries very hard to look “academic”/“science-y”. It’s dishonest to make things look more complicated than they are. The schematics could be used straightforward and common symbols. But no, they chose 4-port squares. It just makes the whole thing look dumb in my opinion. As for which port is which: if you really can’t tell, stick it into CircuitLab on this site (eg in answer editor box) and try it for yourself. That will also be a good answer to your own question :)